# How do I test for an "external user" in CSOM in SharePointOnline

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, csom

How do I test if a user is an "External User" in SharePointOnline?

There is a group called "Everyone except external users" that should be populated with all the users except external users but I do not know how to check to see if the current user is not a member of that group.